# Multiple event listener and adapter

Tags: java, android, events, listener

I am creating my custom event listener for Tree. I have created a listener interface here it is

```
public interface TreeActionListener extends EventListener {
    public void onAddNode(TreeEventObject eventObject);
    public void onRemoveNode(TreeEventObject eventObject);
    public void onRenameNode(TreeEventObject eventObject);
    public void onCreateNode(TreeEventObject eventObject);
}
```

Also I've created custom event object named TreeEventObject here is code

```
public class TreeEventObject extends EventObject {
    private Object dataToPass =null;
    /**
     * Constructs a prototypical Event.
     *
     * @param source The object on which the Event initially occurred.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if source is null.
     */

    public TreeEventObject(Object source, Object dataToPass) {
        super(source);
        this.dataToPass = dataToPass;
    }
    public Object getPassedData() {
        return this.dataToPass;
    }
}
```

And as mentioned in jdk pattern adapter is widely used. It used when I have a lot of methods in listener interface, but I need only one method. 
So I have created my adapter

```
public class TreeActionAdapter implements TreeActionListener {
    @Override
    public void onAddNode(TreeEventObject eventObject) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveNode(TreeEventObject eventObject) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRenameNode(TreeEventObject eventObject) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateNode(TreeEventObject eventObject) {

    }
}
```

But I am a little confused about one thing. I want to write code as clean as possible and  use patterns. So I wonder what is the most elegant way to do the next.
I have class that has my listener as field. 
I have four different events that can be occurred. So what is the right way to fire events. 
I have some ideas, but don't know which is better.

1. Create only one fireEvent method that should check what type of event has been performed. in case of else if. And if to do this way I should create for example enum and create field type in my event object and than in constructor to set it, and check it later in fireEvent method. And depending on type call different methods from listeners list. For instance :

   > ```
   >   if(event.type==NODE_ADD) {
   >     for (TreeActionListener listener: listeners) {
   >         listener.onAddNode(event);
   >     }
   >     }else 
   >     if(event.type==NODE_DELETE) {
   >     for (TreeActionListener listener: listeners) {
   >         listener.onDeleteNode(event);
   >     }
   >      }
   > ```

   2. Use different types of fireEvent methods : fireAddEvent,fireDelete event....... And depending on this also call different listener methods.
   3. Create separate arrays for each type of listener. And use special fireEvent method too.

I don't know what will be better and good practice. Please suggest some other implementation or the best from listed before. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would consider having 4 different fire methods.  Changing behavior off of a method parameter, isn't very clean to me.

Comment: And what do you think about creating intefrace with fireMethods ? That tree class will implement ?

Comment: I don't think that is super important myself.  Just have your class have an add/remove listener methods (Add/remove those listeners from some sort of collection).  Then 4 fire methods (one for each type of event, which would loop though your listeners calling the correct method) and I think life should be pretty good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help ,I will follow your advice. Post your message as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider having 4 different fire methods. Changing behavior off of a method parameter, isn't very clean to me.

Just have your class have an add/remove listener methods (Add/remove those listeners from some sort of collection). Then 4 fire methods (one for each type of event, which would loop though your listeners calling the correct method) and I think life should be pretty good.